# Python - Get variable name with highest interger number

Tags: python

How do I get the variable with the highest interger number, after adding numbers to them?

```
g_dirt4 = 0
g_destiny2 = 0
g_southpark = 0
g_codww2 = 0
g_bfront2 = 0
g_reddead2 = 0
g_fifa18 = 0
g_motogp17 = 0
g_elderscrolls = 0
g_crashbandicoot = 0

#Right here are a lot of if statements which add += 1 to the specific variables

if request.method == "POST":
    #I would like it to print like this:
    print(Highest variable name, corresponding number)
```

How do I do this?

EDIT:

This is my whole script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])



def main():

    g_dirt4 = 0
    g_destiny2 = 0
    g_southpark = 0
    g_codww2 = 0
    g_bfront2 = 0
    g_reddead2 = 0
    g_fifa18 = 0
    g_motogp17 = 0
    g_elderscrolls = 0
    g_crashbandicoot = 0

    d = {'g_dirt4': g_dirt4, 'g_destiny2': g_destiny2, 'g_southpark': g_southpark, 'g_codww2': g_codww2, 'g_bfront2': g_bfront2, 'g_reddead2': g_reddead2, 'g_fifa18': g_fifa18, 'g_motogp17': g_motogp17, 'g_elderscrolls': g_elderscrolls, 'g_crashbandicoot': g_crashbandicoot}

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if (request.form["console"] == "PC"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["console"] == "PS4"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["console"] == "Xbox One"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["console"] == "Maakt niet uit"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["leeftijd"] == "Vanaf 3 jaar"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["leeftijd"] == "Vanaf 7 jaar"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["leeftijd"] == "Vanaf 12 jaar"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["leeftijd"] == "Vanaf 16 jaar"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["leeftijd"] == "Vanaf 18 jaar"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["genre"] == "Shooter"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["genre"] == "Sports"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["genre"] == "Role-playing"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["genre"] == "Platform"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["genre"] == "Simulation"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["multiplayer"] == "Ja"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["multiplayer"] == "Nee"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["splitscreen"] == "Ja"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["splitscreen"] == "Nee"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["geweld"] == "Ja"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["geweld"] == "Nee"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["interesse"] == "balsport"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["interesse"] == "motorsport"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["interesse"] == "geschiedenis/oorlog"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["interesse"] == "films/series"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["interesse"] == "fantasie/fictie"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["interesse"] == "avonturen"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["competitief"] == "Ja"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["competitief"] == "Nee"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["moeteengoeie"] == "single player storyline hebben"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["moeteengoeie"] == "single player open-world hebben"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        #g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["moeteengoeie"] == "multiplayer storyline hebben"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["moeteengoeie"] == "multiplayer open-world hebben"):
        #g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        #g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        #g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["releasedatum"] == "Juni 2017"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["releasedatum"] == "Juli 2017"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["releasedatum"] == "Augustus 2017"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        #g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        #g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["releasedatum"] == "September 2017"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        #g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["releasedatum"] == "Oktober 2017"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        #g_codww2 += 1
        #g_bfront2 += 1
        #g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1

    if (request.form["releasedatum"] == "November 2017 of later"):
        g_dirt4 += 1
        g_destiny2 += 1
        g_southpark += 1
        g_codww2 += 1
        g_bfront2 += 1
        g_reddead2 += 1
        g_fifa18 += 1
        g_motogp17 += 1
        g_elderscrolls += 1
        g_crashbandicoot += 1



    if request.method == "POST":
        print(max(d, key=d.get))
        print("g_dirt4", g_dirt4, "g_destiny2", g_destiny2, "g_southpark", g_southpark, "g_codww2", g_codww2, "g_bfront2", g_bfront2, "g_reddead2", g_reddead2, "g_fifa18", g_fifa18, "g_motogp17", g_motogp17, "g_elderscrolls", g_elderscrolls, "g_crashbandicoot", g_crashbandicoot)
        return redirect("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/8487168_300x300")
```

I don't know if there was an easier way to pull this off, but this works for me aswell. It did cost some time.

Comment: `max(g_dirt4, g_destiny2, ...)`?

Comment: No, I also needed the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
g_dirt4 = 0
g_destiny2 = 0
g_southpark = 0
...

d = {'g_dirt4': g_dirt4, 'g_destiny2': g_destiny2, 'g_southpark': g_southpark}

print(max(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: Is there even a reason to have these as separate variables in the first place? It looks to me like the g_ prefix is an attempt at creating some form of arbitrary data model. It would make much more sense for these to be in a dictionary and reference them from that when required.

Comment: I concur with @JamoBox' comment. However, if you're not able to change the existing code, you can do this:

    num, var_name = max([(v, k) for k, v in locals().items() if k.startswith('g_')])

This gets the dictionary associated with all local variables, picks out the ones that have the g_ prefix, and finds the variable whose value has the highest number associated with it.

Comment: `max(d, key=d.get)` would work. It avoids uneccessarily slow `lambda` calls, and item view/list creations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really work. The log returns this: 2017-06-04 18:04:49 ('g_dirt4', 0)
2017-06-04 18:04:49 g_dirt4 6 g_destiny2 8 g_southpark 6 g_codww2 7 g_bfront2 7 g_reddead2 4 g_fifa18 7 g_motogp17 7 g_elderscrolls 6 g_crashbandicoot 6. It is saying that g_destiny has a score of 8, which is the highest, but it also says that dirt4 with a score of 0 is the highest, but dirt4 has a score of 6..

Comment: You'll have to provide more context to your problem, then. I'm just showing you an example of a data structure that ought to work for this type of problem.

Comment: @Artyer It's a trade-off. Depends on how many items OP has to story in their dictionary. `max(d, d.get)` still only returns the key associated with the highest value. You'd still have to do this to get the value: `(max(d, key=d.get), d[max(d, key=d.get)])`, or something of that nature. The lambda should be fine, unless OP's dealing with thousands and thousands of games.

Comment: @not_a_robot `max_key = max(d, key=d.get); (max_key, d[max_key])`. It's cleaner code as well.

Comment: It always returns dirt4. I editted the post with my full code. (https://jip1912.pythonanywhere.com/) - Dutch

Comment: Ok thanks it works right now. I had to assign the dictionary after the "POST", but what if I get two variables with the same max value? It will print the one with the lowest position value. How do I print them both? 
So in this case I want to print fifa18 and motogp17: 2017-06-07 06:49:00 g_dirt4 8 g_destiny2 6 g_southpark 5 g_codww2 7 g_bfront2 6 g_reddead2 6 g_fifa18 9 g_motogp17 9 g_elderscrolls 5 g_crashbandicoot 6
2017-06-07 06:49:00 ('g_fifa18', 9)